# Edit attribute in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.8.1 and i want to edit the attribute which is already created. but the option such as show in layered navigation is disable.

enter image description here[image: screenshot of non editable field]

[image: layered navigation option is also disable]

Please tell me how to enable this option and edit it again?

Comment: you can not edit `input type for store owner` field. you have to delete it and create a new one.

Comment: If i create new one, then the data which is already used in discription, that is not affected?

Comment: I think yes. you can edit the value by Database in that case. but check the dependence.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old extension which can be used 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-change-attribute-set.html

you have to modify it for magento 1.8

Answer (score 0):

This is set at the time the attribute is created. To edit existing, you will have to edit in the database:

Edit column 'frontend_input' in eav_attribute. Also make sure your 'backend_type' supports the 'frontend_input' type. This is normally decided by Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getBackendTypeByInput($frontend_input)‌​